# update column using where clause a same field's multipul values

Tags: sql

Dear all, 
i need to update a table using same filed's multiple value.
Let: `update test_table set column1=123 where column2=100,200,300......`
I mean column 2 have multiple values.Now how i write the query??
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
update test_table set column1=123 where column2 IN(100,200,300)
```

look here for a tutorial:
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the match should happen where `column2`'s value is one of the items in your list, use:

```
UPDATE test_table 
    SET column1=123 
        WHERE column2 IN (100,200,300, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

use FIND_IN_SET

```
FIND_IN_SET("id",test_table.column2)
```